# Laravel With Nginx and Docker Deployment /storage/app/public/ images not working

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, web-deployment

I've deployed a laravel project on an ubuntu server with default installation of nginx on the host(Without Dockerizing it) then the laravel app is dockerized and is forwarded using a reverse proxy from nginx so image loading from {url}/storage/app/public/ is not working. it uploads files fine but it returns 404 when tried to access ,it works on localhost but not on the server

Comment: Make sure you have linked your storage, I always froget to do it on server side